# Search for string in all files in current drive using regex on windows

Tags: regex, windows, findstr

I am trying to search for an email address on my harddisk. I know that it should be something like:

> b************m@e******.com

and this is why I came up with this regex:

> b.{12}m@e.{6}.com

I found that `findstr` could be useful for this job and tried:

```
findstr /R b.{12}m@e.{6}\.com c:\*.*
```

but it doesn't find anything even if I added a file with an email that should match that regex of mine, this one for example: `b8726ngs.poinm@e123456.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing this with the following PowerShell command instead (note depending on where you start this could take a long time to run):

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -Recurse -File | Where-Object { (Get-Content $_.FullName) -match "b.{12}m@e.{6}.com" }
```

You will get red error messages for areas of the disk that you don't have permission to access. Run PowerShell as Administrator for the widest possible search.

Add a file path to Get-ChildItem in order to set a base directory if you wish, otherwise it will start in the directory you are currently in.

**Explanation of parameters:**

- `-Recurse` searches the current directory and all sub-directories.
- `-File` returns only files (not directories).
- `Get-Content $_.FullName` gets the contents of each file.
- `-match` performs the regex comparison.

Comment: No, it's inside the file! I'm sorry I didn't point this out as I thought it's obvious. So more likely that email address is inside e .txt file but just to make sure I want to find all files

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that's what `findstr` so it should have been obvious! I've amended my answer with one that will search in the contents of files.

Comment: I have tried your solution and it works just that when I search the root hdd, my CPU goes to 95% and it also the powershell consumes a lot of memory - started building 1.5 Gb in less than 15 minutes so can you please tell me how to only search for *.txt files?

Comment: `Get-childitem *.txt -recurse`

Comment: Thank you - It's now running and cpu is @ 100% and same for the Memory. Any way I can decrease its usage?

Answer (score 0):

There are regex and then there are regex. Looks like findstr is not very powerful.

```
findstr /R "b............m@e......\.com" *.*
```

This is only on the findstr part not working.
Do this with appropriate precautions, e.g. inside a directory which only contains readable files.

Comment: Running this from c:\ it will throw FINDSTR: Cannot open hiberfil.sys FINDSTR: Cannot open pagefile.sys FINDSTR: Cannot open swapfile.sys and then stops so I guess it will not find in all subdirectories.